# Multiple database access vs joining on 2 tables performance

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, web, server

Tables are:

> Users (id, name) 
> Friends (id1, id2)

I am getting the IDs of the friends of a particular user from Friends table and making multiple access to get the friend's name  (for each of these friends IDs i make an access to the user table to get the name)

The simple way is doing one access and Joining the 2 tables, but it will conflict with the structure of the server code.

**Is there major performance drop when making multiple access in large scale database or it is not a problem since the these accesses are from the server and not the client ?**

Comment: Its a lot of extra overhead when you could could get the data in one hit. What would the maximum number of friends be?

Comment: @DaleK 1000 for example. Also I am using PDO, and I found this link https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiexec which states that it is slightly faster than performing the same query again and again, as it does query parsing only once. If there is not a big performance difference between multiple access and joining I may consider doing multiple access and keep the structure of the code

Comment: No one can tell you how much the difference will be, so measure it. If your server code is on the same server as your database then it will be very different to if they are on 2 different boxes because of the network traffic. Its certainly inefficient, you're asking SQL Server for 1000 names 1 at a time instead of all at once. But whether there is any noticeable performance hit only you can measure.

Comment: I this question about whether to use a join or to make 1000 separate queries? As @DaleK indicates, if you only have 1 friend then it might not appear to make a huge difference. But given that your round trip latency of each call is likely to be far more than the actual database lookup, it would be crazy not to letter database do its job and do a join. Let the server do as much of the work as you can, in one go.